# Substantial / Total / Material Derivative Contradiction

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fluid-dynamics

We want to find the material derivative in terms of the spatial representation (classic case).

$\phi$ : Temperature, entropy etc,
$x_{0}$ : Reference coordinate,
$x$ : Spatial / eulerian coordinate

Let $\phi=xt$ and $x= x_{0}(1+t)$ where $x_{0} = c $

$\dfrac{d\phi}{dt} = \left(\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\right)_{t} \dfrac{dx}{dt}+ \left(\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}\right)_{x}$

Therefore, the total derivative in spatial and material coordinates is the following

$\dfrac{d\phi}{dt} = tx_{0} + x$

To obtain the pure spatial representation, you find the material coordinate in terms of the spatial coordinate.

$x_{0} = \dfrac{x}{1+t}$

Lastly, you perform the substitution into the total derivative yielding the classic result.

$\dfrac{d\phi}{dt} = t\dfrac{x}{1+t} + x$

Since $x_{0} = c$,  how can the above substitution be valid for any $x, t$ when it appears only valid for $x(t)= x_{0}(1+t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The material derivative is the temporal rate of change of the scalar $\phi$ following the path of a fluid particle.  In a Lagrangian framework, the location of a fluid particle at time $t$ initially with coordinate $x_0$ is specified by a smooth function $\xi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ where

$$x = \xi(x_0,t) = x_0(1 + t).$$

Each fluid particle is associated with a different $x_0$ which you are mistakenly interpreting as a fixed constant.

The material derivative is

$$\frac{d}{dt} \phi(\xi(x_0,t),t) = D_1\phi(\xi(x_0,t),t) \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial t} + D_2\phi(\xi(x_0,t),t), $$

where $D_1$ and $D_2$ denote partial derivatives with respect to the first and second arguments.  (Part of you confusion may be due to your notation).

This reduces to

$$\frac{d}{dt} \phi(\xi(x_0,t),t)  =tx_0 + \xi(x_0,t), $$

and written in terms of Eulerian coordinates

$$\frac{d \phi}{dt}   =t\frac{x}{1+t} + x. $$

Comment: Your answer implies the material derivative holds x0 constant. This probaby explains special big D notation.

Comment: @Matt:  Writing $\phi(x,t)$ in the Eulerian representation there is a a spatial argument and a temporal argument so $D_1$ is the partial with respect to the spatial argument and $D_2$ is the partial with respect to the temporal argument.  Once you start considering the material derivative, you add a time dependence to $x$ and you are correct that this derivative holds $x_0$ fixed.  It gives the rate of change with time as you move through space tracking a fluid particle.